# Wake up main thread from sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, sleep, wakeup

How can I wake up the main thread (currently sleeping because of a sleep() function call) from inside a child thread (without the child thread terminating)?

I want to make my main thread wait for a signal from a child thread without using an infinite loop or anything else that eats CPU power.

The only things I found about this subject mentioned the main thread waking up a child thread but not the other way around.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal ?

Comment: Don't use sleep(), but rather use an appropriate 'blocking-until' function and be cooperative.

Comment: Use `pthread_kill` to send a signal to a specific thread.

Comment: Event, semaphore or condition variable with a timed wait.  All non-trivial OS have some such synchro primitive that could be used.  Create the synchro object in the main thread, signal it to the work thread as part of the thread creation argument, wait/seep on it in the main thread whenever you need to, signal it in the child thread when you're ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is pause the thread until it receives a signal from another thread, that's exactly what the [pause function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) is for.

> pause() causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a
>          signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the
>          invocation of a signal-catching function.